# If two people sign through an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

There are two signatories on my signature process, and I don't know how to get two people to sign through one envelope. I created an envelope for the first signature, then saved the signed envelope as a document, and then passed this document Generate a new envelope.
There are too many methods in DocuSign, and I don’t know which method can be used to complete the signature between two people. I hope someone can give me a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some copy/pasta JSON you can use to get started:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "data_here",
            "name": "Order acknowledgement",
            "fileExtension": "txt",
            "documentId": "1"
        },
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "test@testing.com",
                "name": "test1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "name": "test 2",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```